# Easy to guess project id on google cloud platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it important that the project id will be unguessable?

I know that the project id should be globally unique but is there any danger with making it easy to guess? For example, is it ok to use 'mycompany-production' and 'mycompany-staging' or should I use 'p-193423234' and 's-98712334' for production and staging?

Can someone exploit me by knowing the project id?

Comment: What Google Project-ID are you referencing? I don't know any Project-app in G-Suite. For all products I know off, you define the permissions by their Sharing-settings. If you share 'anonymously' (and only then), then yes, the URL should be very hard to guess.

Comment: This is the project id: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158840?hl=en

Comment: I don't think you need to keep those ID's secret. Normally things are not secured that way because it's a poor way to secure. But maybe someone else can confirm this.

Comment: Even if you implement the later, its not hard to automate requests and check which one was successful. So someone determined to guess it would do it either way. I believe in Google you can set access type (e.g. access for everyone with link or only whitelisted members), the later is what you're probably after if you don't want people to access your document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my opinion about this is, as long as they are not an administrator for your account or the project owner no one will be able to access your project.

If you try calling Google Cloud Platform they will ask for the email address
associated with the billing account and the last 4 characters on your billing
account number for verification and after the call they will send you a summary of the call and the details of the conversation.